# how ngRoute works in background when include as dependency in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When we write `angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);` what exactly dependencies here mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to be precise ngRoute is nothing but a simple angular module like

`angular.module('ngRoute',['ng'])` in which has $routeProvider

```
 `angular.module('ngRoute',[]).provider('$roteProvider',[function(){}]).services('$route',function(){}).service('$routeParam',function(){})`
```

Its better to see the angular project in github https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies means the list of modules that particular module in your case 'app' is dependent on , you when you state them as dependencies they get injected in the module at initialization and become available for usage